# Help with Maths equation

Tags: braces

I am very new to any form of Latex and markdown coding but I am trying to assist my student as much as possible. He is visually impaired and is finding markdown, with maths in LaTex, really accessible so I am formatting his work as best as I can using that.
However today I came across the attached example and I really don't know where to start!
I can provide it in hard copy braille ok but I would like to know how it can be done in code
Can anyone help please....this is for an almost complete novice[image: ![example]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YSsF.png)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4):

for such equations is ˙in `amsmath` package defined environment `cases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
P(X=x) = 
\begin{cases}
  0.1   &   x=-2, -1    \\
  \beta &   x=0.1       \\
  0.2   &   x=2
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. I can't yet begin to understand how it works, i wish I had more time to get to grip with it all. I have pasted it into stackedit (i am a beginner and my student uses the markdown,and by removing some code and it leaves me with the equation still perfectly in the window, but i'd love to know more about how it all works, idiots guide, or maybe you could break down a little what you have coded for me. I ended up with the following code still: $P(X=x) = 
\begin{cases}
  0.1   &   x=-2, -1    \\
  \beta &   x=0.1       \\
  0.2   &   x=2
\end{cases}$

Comment: @LynnH, `$` is for inline equation. For displayed equation with out numbering you should use `\begin{equation*} ...\end{equation*}` or shorter `\[ ... \]`.  I'm not familiar with Markdown, so I can't help you with it, if this is problem. I also sugest you to read some introductory text about writing math: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics

Comment: Hi, for my humble opinion the origin of code use it not seem in LaTeX. The brace is in TikZ. I not know this bracket in the usual LaTeX.